# Find pdf function for given cdf,

Tags: probability

The random variables given for the CDF distribution function:

$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    0, &  x\leq\frac{3}{2}   \\
    a(4x^2-12x+9), & \frac{3}{2}<x\leq 3 \\
    1, & x>3
\end{cases}
$$

$a)$ Find value of parametric $a$, and $p_X(x)$ (PDF).

$b)$ find the probability that the random variables in $(0,2)$

My attemp is: First part
$a)$ $$F_X(3^-)=F_X(3^+)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 3^-}F_X(x)=1\rightarrow \lim_{x\to 3^-}(a(4x^2-12x+9))=1\rightarrow a=\frac{1}{9}$$,

but I didnt know it is correct in this form.

Now we have:
$$
F_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    0, &  x\leq\frac{3}{2}   \\
    \frac{1}{9}(4x^2-12x+9), & \frac{3}{2}<x\leq 3 \\
    1, & x>3
\end{cases}
$$
Now find the derivation of the given function $F_X(x)$

$$[F_X(x)]'=
p_X(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
    0, &  x\in R-(\frac{3}{2},3)   \\
    \frac{4}{9}(2x-3), & \frac{3}{2}<x< 3 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now for the second part

$b)$

$$P(X\in(0,2))=F(2)-F(0)=\frac{1}{9}((4\cdot 4-12\cdot 2+9)-(4\cdot 0-12\cdot 0 +9))=-\frac{8}{9}????$$
where is my wrong. or I have to replace it $p_X(x)$

Help me please. Thanks.

i don't know where i went wrong. Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $x<{3\over 2}$, the CDF becomes $0$ from the above equation and for $1.5<x<3$ it is calculated from the middle one which gives you $F(2)={1\over 9}$. That's where your mistake is.

Comment: can you tell me in more detail how, and is it good value of $a$

Comment: Your $a$ is fine. Your mistake is where you have substituted $x=0$ in $a(4x^2-12x+9)$ to find $F(2)$ and implicitly presumed ${3\over 2}<0<3$ which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: $a=1/9$ is good. $$P(X\in(0,2))=F(2)-F(0)=\frac{1}{9}((4\cdot 4-12\cdot 2+9)-0=\frac{1}{9}$$

Comment: Yes. Now corrected.

Comment: thanku sir, you were very clear and very accurate

Comment: Glad to help you. Good luck!